# Combining validation methods in jQuery Validation plugin with "or" instead of "and"

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-validate

In the jQuery Validation plugin there are a couple of methods that do the same thing, but for different locales, for example `dateISO` and `dateDE`, that both validate date formatting. How do I combine these so that the input element accepts *either*?

Let's say I have an `<input type="text" name="dateInput" id="dateInput" />` in my form, and I want to allow users to enter only dates in this field. However, I want to allow for several different date formats - for example, the user should be able to enter **either** an ISO date **or** a date formatted accoding to German date rules.

If I do

```
rules: { dateInput: { required: true, dateISO: true, dateDE: true } }
```

the form will *never* be valid, as both date formats will be required and that requirement can never be fulfilled. Is there a way to combine these as an "or" instead of as an "and", without having to write my own validation method?

And if I do have to write my own, how do I make it as generic as possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While you can combine the regexes like Reigel has, you can also just call those methods directly (in case they change!), like this:

```
$.validator.addMethod("dateISODE", function(value, element) { 
    return $.validator.methods.dateISO.apply(this, arguments) 
        || $.validator.methods.date.apply(this, arguments); 
}, "Please enter a valid ISO or German date");
```

Now I have `date` instead of `dateDE` here, because in newer versions of the plugin [`dateDE` was removed](http://bassistance.de/2009/11/30/release-validation-plugin-1-6/). It's now in a [localization file](http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.7/localization/methods_de.js) that just overrides the `date` method.  If you're using an older version that's fine, just stick with `dateDE`.

[You can try a demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/4JWAe/)

---

**Update for comments:**  A more generic form would look like this:

```
$.validator.addMethod("oneOf", function(value, element, params) {
  for(p in params) {
    if(params.hasOwnProperty(p) && 
       $.validator.methods[p].apply(this, [value, element, params[p]]))
      return true;
  }
  return false;
}, "Please enter a valid date");
```

The rules would look like this:

```
$("form").validate({
  rules: {
    dateFieldName: { oneOf: { dateISO:true, date:true } }
  }
});
```

[You can try a demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/4JWAe/2/), this takes any number of validator functions and runs them, at least one must return `true` for it to succeed.

Comment: Ideally, I'd like to send in an options object of the same syntax as the one I use to apply rules, and then combine all of them in a way similar to what you describe. Is this possible? (I have tried, but I keep running into problems with me not knowing what my function context is...)

Comment: @Tomas - `rules` doesn't iterate like that, so I'm not sure what you can accomplish that route, each rule **inside** this element's rules object is what executes, so this is one of those, being `dateISODE: true` in this case.  You're wanting to go up a level, saying `dateInput:....something`, I don't even know what the syntax would look like.  In short, no, I don't think you're going to get out of using custom methods for this, at least not without modifying the validation plugin's core code...that's a path to stay away from :)

Comment: Maybe I've misunderstood how `rules` work, or expressed myself vaguely. What I'm after is being able to declare the rules with syntax like `rules:{ myinput: { oneOf: {dateISO:true,dateDE:true} } }`. That *would* be possible if I could iterate over the arguments to `oneOf`, and call those functions with their correct arguments - are you saying this is *per se* impossible?

Comment: @Tomas - That description was much clearer...I updated the answer to show how to do exactly that :)

Comment: Brilliant - that's **exactly** what I was after! Kudos! =)

Comment: @NickCraver I tried your example on jsfiddle, but it seems to accept only ISO dates and not dates like "1 august 2013".  What am I missing?

Comment: I'd love to be able to specify arbitrary methods and have it display the correct error message based on the underlying message.  'Please enter a valid date' wouldn't be appropriate, for example, if I said `rules: { myinput: { oneOf: { foo: true, bar: true} } }` where foo and bar are different each time.  Any way to get it to display the underlying error message for the one it failed on?

Answer (score 0):

```
dateISO: function(value, element) {
     return this.optional(element) || /^\d{4}[\/-]\d{1,2}[\/-]\d{1,2}$/.test(value);
},
dateDE: function(value, element) {
     return this.optional(element) || /^\d\d?\.\d\d?\.\d\d\d?\d?$/.test(value);
}
```

[source](http://view.jquery.com/trunk/plugins/validate/jquery.validate.js)

lets combine it... :)

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("dateISOorDE", function(value, element) { 
    return this.optional(element) || /^\d{4}[\/-]\d{1,2}[\/-]\d{1,2}$/.test(value) || /^\d\d?\.\d\d?\.\d\d\d?\d?$/.test(value); 
}, "Please specify the correct date");
```

Comment: Yeah, I figured I could do this. But that means that each time I want to combine two validation methods, I'd have to do this work all over again. And the same thing goes for adding support for a third one in this method. What if I decide I want to support Swedish dates as well? What if I need support for multicultural numbers(not all cultures use "." for decimal markers - Sweden, for one, uses ","...)? The approach you suggest is a valid last resort, but I'd much rather have something generic and reusable.

Comment: Now that I think about it, just being able to reference other functions in my new function is good enough as an intermediate solution. Instead of (like you) copy-pasting code, is there any way to actually *call* the other validation methods in my new method?