# ASP.NET MVC 3 not accepting my German date format settings - why?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, date-formatting

I have a new ASP.NET MVC 3 project, and MVC and Razor are all brand new to me... can't figure this one out.

I have a dev machine on US-English Win7 x64, running English versions of VS 2010 Pro SP1 and ASP.NET MVC 3. But the app I'm working on is for a local client, and needs to be all in German and use all the formatting and defaults commonly used here.

In my view model, I have defined a variable of type `DateTime` and augmented it with some extra hints as to how to display (and edit) it - I need the Swiss-German date formatting, which is: `day.month.year` (in that order, separated by dots `.` - not slashes)

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    [Display(Name = "Gültig am")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString="dd.MM.yyyy", ApplyFormatInEditMode=true)]
    public DateTime ValidAt { get; set; }
}
```

(of course, there are more properties in that view model, but those aren't relevant just now)

In my Razor view, I simply use the default stuff set up by the ASP.NET MVC 3 `Add View` T4 template:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.ValidAt)
```

Trouble is: if I enter something like `13.06.2011` (13th of June, 2011) which I believe is valid and conforming to my display and editing formats, I am still getting a client-side validation saying that `The value '13.06.2011' is invalid` - **WHY???**

There must be something really fundamental (and probably totally silly) that I'm missing here....

Even though I have set all of this up,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you use for client validation? Did you look at [Combining validation methods in jQuery Validation plugin with "or" instead of "and"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3138646/combining-validation-methods-in-jquery-validation-plugin-with-or-instead-of-an) ?

Comment: I haven't set up anything special - I just started a plain, run-of-the-mill ASP.NET MVC 3 project. So I guess that's just the default stuff Microsoft packs into ASP.NET MVC 3 client-side, right now

Comment: this article was helpfull for me http://haacked.com/archive/2010/05/10/globalizing-mvc-validation.aspx

Comment: very interesting link - I'll have to check it out! THanks

Comment: try only adding this script http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/4.0/1/globalization/DE-DE.JS
It may be everything you need.